# Is there an easy way to index by a binary vector / mask?

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I would like to be able to extract elements from a list where indices are specified by a binary mask.

To provide an example, I would like to have a function `BinaryIndex` doing the following:

```
foo = {a, b, c}
mask = {True, False, True}
BinaryIndex[mask, foo]
(* expected output *) {a, c}
```

Is there such a function built-in? I would be able to come up with some implementation, but I would like to have this performance-optimized. If there is no such built-in function, what would be a good approach to make this fast?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Pick[foo, mask]
(* {a, c}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this question is about performance, I'd like to add that often it's better to work with lists of integers than lists of booleans since lists of integers can be packed. For example, if you want to pick the positive elements from an array using `Pick`, you can either use `Positive` to make a boolean selector list or `UnitStep` to make an integer selector list:

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100000];
With[{sel = Positive[list]}, Pick[list, sel]; // RepeatedTiming]
With[{sel = UnitStep[list]}, Pick[list, sel, 1]; // RepeatedTiming]
```

> {0.0065, Null}
>
> {0.00099, Null}

As you can see, `UnitStep` is significantly faster in the `Pick`ing step because `UnitStep[list]` is a packed array:

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[list] (* True *)
Developer`PackedArrayQ[Positive[list]] (* False *)
Developer`PackedArrayQ[UnitStep[list]] (* True*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Booleans in *Mathematica* is that they cannot be stored in packed arrays, reducing the efficiency of their processing. Suppose that `b` is already a packed vector of integers, e.g., `b = Developer`ToPackedArray[Boole[mask]]`. Then you should be able to obtain your result faster with

```
result = Pick[foo, b, 1];
```

You may also try the undocumented function `` Random`Private`PositionsOf `` which can be used to determine the actual list `idx` of *indices* of `1`-entries in the array `b`; this may be useful if you can reuse `idx` multiple times.

```
idx = Random`Private`PositionsOf[b,1];
result = foo[[idx]];
```